# Wrapping working code in a function and it stops working

Tags: r, function, scoping

I have some code that works quite well, and I have it repeated in
the same format in my code several times, so I've tried to wrap
it in a generalised function and as soon as I do that, it stops
working.  I have no idea why but I've missed something
basic. Pleased if you could show me my basic error. Thx. J

function that works in the code is of format:

```
vec1[ as.logical (vec1 == val1 & vec2 >= val2)] <- val3
```

so this changes the value in vec1 from its current value to val3,
when the conditions are met.  However if I create a function such
as

```
ChangeState <- function (vec1, vec2, val1, val2, val3) {
    vec1[as.logical(vec1 == va1 & vec2 >= val2)] <- val3
}
```

And then I execute it as such:

```
ChangeState(inputvec1, inputvec2, value1, value2, value3)
```

nothing happens, it doesn't alter any values in vec1 even though
it should.  It runs and doesn't throw any errors or warnings. Could this be a "scoping" problem? If so how can I fix it?

Comment: you need to return Vec1 in your function... `return(Vec1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sotos has stated, you're missing a `return` statement.  What is happening in your function is a silent return. Consider the following example. If we define the `add` function as

```
add <- function(x, y){
  z <- x + y
}
```

and then call

```
add(1, 2)
```

It appears as if nothing is returned.  There is no output printed to the console.

On the other hand, look at what happens when we assign the result of the function to an object:

```
z <- add(1, 2)
z
```

> `[1] 3`

So without a `return` statement, the function can return a value silently. It is conventional to provide a `return` statement of some form (be it implicit or explicit).

An important caveat for your function is that you *need* a return statement.  Whereas you are only performing replacement on a subset of `vec1`, if you do not use a return statement, your function will only return the subset of `vec1` that satisfies `as.logical(vec1 == va1 & vec2 >= val2)`. Thus, to get the output you (presumably) desire, you should use

```
ChangeState <- function (vec1, vec2, val1, val2, val3) {
    vec1[as.logical(vec1 == va1 & vec2 >= val2)] <- val3
    vec1 # implicit return
}
```

or

```
ChangeState <- function (vec1, vec2, val1, val2, val3) {
    vec1[as.logical(vec1 == va1 & vec2 >= val2)] <- val3
    return(vec1) # explicit return
}
```